# Change fields based on Dropdown Selection and submit with ID

Tags: javascript, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working for Ruby project I have a requirement to do, I am using 3 tables like question question_types, answers. I am fetching fields from question_types and making it as drop-down. While selection one value from drop-down the fields should change accordingly and after submitting it should save it with drop-down selected value.Those three tables have relations.

```
<%=f.label :QuestionType %> <br />
<%= f.collection_select :question_type_id, QuestionType.all, :id, :name,:class=> 'dropdown'  %>

<div class="toggle" id="question_type_id" style="display:none;">
<%= f.input :target_date%>
</div>

<div class="toggle" id="question_type_id"  style="display:none;">
<%= f.input :question %>
</div>

<div class="field" >
<%= f.label :Priority %><br>
<%= f.collection_select :priority_id, Priority.all, :id, :name %>
</div>

</div>
<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>

$('.dropdown').change(function() { 
$('form .toggle').hide();
var divClass = $('.dropdown').val().toLowerCase();
$('.' + divClass).show();
});
```

I want to save these fields with ID selected from Drop-down. Please help me

Comment: Can you explain this "fields should change accordingly"?

Comment: yeah sure i will explain clearly.. 3 tables 'nc_questions','question_types','answers'. In 'nc_questions' i am using primary key of question_types table. It will fetch all the question types like "Multiple", "Interview Questions". If i select Multiple then Multiple Questionnaire form will be shown after submitting it should store with question_type_id value

Comment: In this line `<%= f.collection_select :question_id, QuestionType.all, :id, :name,:class=> 'dropdown'  %>` you have given `question_id`,shouldn't it be `question_type_id`?

Comment: yeah i have given that one too...I want to save it with dropdown selected ID value

Comment: May be this could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12020606/filling-input-field-based-on-dropdown-menu-selection-with-javascript?rq=1

Comment: Yeah i tried that too.. But it's not working